# ActiveMQ Master/Slave Pair with Network of Brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

I was able to set up Network of Brokers with store and forward strategy and working fine. I was given bigger machines now and would like to set up Master/Slave pair within the network of brokers. I understand Masters don't need any config changes but Slaves should indicate its corresponding master with URI. However, I'm not very clear on what uri to specify in the client. I'm using 5.6 release.

For example: Two machines with MasterA, SlaveB on 1 machine, and MasterB, SlaveA on another machine. No Network connectors between Masters and Slaves but network connectors between MasterA and MasterB. I hope that I'm right till this point. What about client uri? I'm currently using nio protocol at the clients like `failover:(nio:localhost1:61616,nio:localhost2:61616)?randomize=true`. I specify randomize=true to balance the load between the brokers.

Please suggest what client URI should I use? Should I include all brokers URI or just masters URI? Can I still use nio protocol? I prefer to use `randomize=true` so that load will be balanced.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, the client uri should contain 4 brokers, both pairs of master/slave uris.
For the network connectors, they will need to be prepared to bridge master to master or master to slave, which ever is available. 
There is a new masterslave: discovery agent in 5.6 that simplifies the configuration for a networkconnector. 
http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html#NetworksofBrokers-MasterSlaveDiscovery

Comment: sorry it took so long to fix the link but that one should be more stable going forward